# Use wildcards with perforce move

Tags: version-control, perforce

I would like to move files filtered using wildcards to subfolders, however perforce move does not accept my usage of the wild card.

given this structure

```
filea_mk1.txt
fileb_mk2.txt
mk1/
mk2/
```

to move all files some thing like `p4 move ./... ./mk1/...` works, however when replacing the selected file to use wild cards I get:

```
p4 edit filea_mk1.txt
p4 move *_mk1*.* ./mk1/...
Usage: move [-c changelist#] [ -f ] [ -k ] [-t type] from to
Missing/wrong number of arguments.
```

I have thought about using `p4 fstat` as that does accept the wildcards, and could then pass filenames into to xargs.

```
p4 fstat *_mk1*.*
```

However I can not get the `-A` options correct to only show client names.

---

### TL;DR

Is there a way to filter *_mk1*.* into the mk1 folder and *_mk2*.* into the mk2 folder, using perforce commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that what's happening here is that your operating system shell is expanding the asterisk wildcards in your command, so the actual command that the Perforce server is seeing is:

```
`p4 move filea_mk1.txt fileb_mk1.txt ./mk1/...`
```

and that command has three file-spec arguments, rather than the expected two file-spec arguments, hence the `Usage:` message that you receive.

By using operating-system filenames (`*_mk1*.*` and  `./mk1/...`), you are providing the file-spec arguments in what Perforce calls "local" syntax.

But this causes your operating system shell to think it should expand the wildcards, when what you want is to have the Perforce server expand the wildcards.

You can try using different quoting strategies for your arguments, to defeat that local wildcard expansion, but this is a situation where you can benefit from using one of the other forms of file-spec syntax, either "client" syntax" or "depot" syntax.

For example, suppose that your client root is actually located in a section of the depot that begins with the path `//depot/projects/project1/main/`.

Then, you could specify your command as:

```
`p4 move //depot/projects/project1/main/*_mk1*.* //depot/projects/project1/main/mk1/*_mk1*.*`
```

In this case, these file-spec arguments will **not** be seen as syntax that your operating-system shell should expand, so it will leave the arguments alone and pass them unaltered to the server, so that the Perforce server can perform the wildcard expansion, rather than allowing your shell to perform the wildcard expansion.

Note that I also re-specified your wildcard expansion slightly. The Perforce `move` command, like the `integrate` command and several other commands, is typically happiest if the "wildcards on the left side" match up with the "wildcards on the right side", so that when it is constructing new destination file names for the files being moved, it can replace the wild-carded elements 1-1 with the wild-carded elements from the source file names.

Comment: The explanation about wildcard matching is very insightful, incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this:

```
p4 move *_mk1*.* ./mk1/...
```

Do this:

```
p4 move "*_mk1*.*" "mk1/*_mk1*.*"
```

Note the double quotes to keep the shell from expanding the asterisks.

Alternatively, this simpler form will probably work fine unless the paths are trickier than your example makes them appear:

```
p4 move ..._mk1... mk1/..._mk1...
```